# errors for creating arabic text files in python,

Tags: python, unicode, arabic

I write a python code to read Arabic text in files under a specific folder and remove unwanted symbols (e.g. (, ) , $, . . . etc), then save all Arabic clear text into another folder.

the problem is the the code creates files with the following text:

\'c3\'cb\'d1\'ca
\f1
\
\f0
\'dd\'ed\'c7
\f1
\
\f0
\'e1\'c3\'e4
\f1
\
\f0
\'c8\'d8\'e1\'e5\'c7

not in Arabic language form.

How I can read and write text in Arabic form only.

The code

```
import sys, os
import codecs
import unicodedata
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

if not os.path.exists(corpus_clean):
    os.makedirs(corpus_clean)

reload(sys)

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
def readUnicodeDataFrom(inputDir):
    unicode_input = codecs.open(inputDir, encoding='utf8', mode='r')
    unicode_data = unicode_input.read()
    norm_data = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode_data).encode('utf8', 'ignore')
    norm_words = word_tokenize(norm_data)
    unicode_input.close
    return norm_words

def removeCharFrom(mylist):
    mylist = [x for x in mylist if not (x.isdigit() 
                                         or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]   

    to_remove = ['*','#', '/', '.', '...', ':','-','_',',',';','<','>','|','\\','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','?',')','(','%','&','+','$','^','!','"','[',']']

    for char in mylist:
        if char in to_remove:
            mylist.remove(char) 
    return mylist


def writeUnicodeDataTo(outputDir, listOfWords):
    unicode_output = codecs.open(outputDir, encoding='utf8', mode='w+')
    for word in listOfWords:
        word = unicode(word, errors='ignore')
        unicode_output.write(word+'\n')#.encode('utf8', 'ignore'))
    unicode_output.seek(0)
        unicode_output.close

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 1
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
             if name !='.DS_Store':
                f = open(os.path.join(root, name))
                norm_words = readUnicodeDataFrom(os.path.join(root, name))
                uniq_words = removeCharFrom(norm_words)
                writeUnicodeDataTo(os.path.join(corpus_clean, name), uniq_words)
                print ('The file number: '+str(i)+'\n\n')
                i+=1
                for j in range(len(uniq_words)):
                    print(u''+norm_words[j])
  f.close()
```

Comment: Do not encode again after `codecs.open`. Both when reading and writing. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
norm_data = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode_data).encode('utf8', 'ignore')
```

change to

```
norm_data = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode_data)
```

and

```
word = unicode(word, errors='ignore')
unicode_output.write(word+'\n')#.encode('utf8', 'ignore'))
```

change to

```
unicode_output.write(word+'\n')
```

#### Reason

The problem is that you shouldn't encode again after `codecs.open(inputDir, encoding='utf8', mode='r')`. `codecs` already does it for you.

The same problem when you write to file using `unicode_output.write(word+'\n')`.

Comment: thanks sir. for your helping, its working but in some files gives me the following error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 2001: invalid start byte

Comment: this one as well

Comment: I think I found the solution for this problem: the extension of the files in rtf I wil check it and give u the feedback soon

Comment: I found the problem, some text it works without any problem and other not. That's back to the format of mac OS in Arabic text, because the files which I gathered from Linx are work without any problem. By the way, thanks a lot for your helping :)

Comment: Glad to help out. My honor if you accept my answer as the best.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read and write the files in binary mode:

```
...
unicode_input = codecs.open(inputDir, encoding='utf8', mode='rb')
...
unicode_output = codecs.open(outputDir, encoding='utf8', mode='wb')
```

Comment: I change your suggestions and its works but I found another problem such as the following: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 2001: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

Hi does the following code help?
`

```
with open('arabic.txt','r') as in_file:
     new_text=[]
     arabic_text = in_file.readlines()
     for each_line in arabic_text:
         each_line.translate(None,'!@##$%^**()')
         new_text.extends(each_line)
with open('new_arabic.txt'.'a') as out_file:
     for line in new_text:
         out_file.write(line.encode(utf-8))`
```

Comment: @abdel-kaderMagdy  if this code helped then can you please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: I did bro, but no change I don't know why